# Could not connect to glassfish ip address on windows server 2008

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3, glassfish-embedded

I have developed a servlet and deployed it on my server -windows server 2008- 
the server have an ip and the port of the glassfish 3.1.2 server is 11188, when i call the servlet from the local host it works fine, but when i call the server via the ip address this error shown could not connect to NN.NN.NNN.NNN:11188  ;N: is a number.

How do i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the port 11188 in the firewall.

Comment: I did, but the problem is still

Answer (score 0):

I was forget to define the port 11188 on the approved ports on the hoster control panel